# How can I change my review decision?

Tags: support, review

I wrongly assessed a review question. I should have skipped it, can I change my review?

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to change your review.

But it isn't such a big deal since $6$ people are required to [delete](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25229/the-difference-between-delete-and-recommend-deletion) a question with "recommend delete" action (or delete vote) and "recommend close" [usually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204705/how-many-recommend-close-votes-is-too-many) needs more than $6$ votes.

Comment: Corollary: be sure of whatever you're clicking on in there, and don't "robo-review".